# How to specify a function for use with improved euler code

Tags: matlab, ode, euler-math-toolbox

I am writing code to do improved euler method on a 1st order ODE. My difficulty is in the declaration of the function. While the syntax seems correct matlab does not know whether to handle this as a vector and use .^2 or use ^2 when squaring x and y. I purposely did not use a function saved on disk; I want all code to be contained within m file.

I would also like to output 2 columns X and Y next to each other at the end with column headers.

Any suggestions? Part of this code was copied from Edwards and Penny Elementary Diffeq. Thanks.  MM

Matlab code:

```
clc; clear; clear axes; clf; close all; 
%Inputs
x(1)=0; y(1)=1;
f=@(x,y)( y+sqrt(x^2+y^2) );
a=1; b=3; n=3;
h=(b-a)/n;
% 
X=x;
Y=y;
for i=1:n;
k1=f(x,y);
k2=f(x+h,y+h*k1);
k=(k1+k2)/2;
x=x+h;
y=y+h*k;
X=[X;x];
Y=[Y;y];
end

% output X and Y
  table=[X,Y]
  table'
```

Comment: I'm confused what the problem is. The matlab code you provided seems to be running, at least in Matlab R2018b in which I just tested it. Since x, y are just values and not vectors you could just initialize them without the index 1, as `x=0; y=1;`. However the code works as is. To output X,Y in a column just use `[X,Y]`.

Comment: I am clearing things out of memory between multiple runs of Euler, improved Euler and Runge-Kutta routines. Have I forgot something? I have been getting intermittent stoppages at function definition. Thanks. MM

Comment: By "clearing out memory between multiple runs", I guess you refer `clear`. That's alright. I checked if your code is running, not your Euler/Runge-Kutta scheme validity if that's what you are asking. Intermittent stoppages? That's weird. What is such a stoppage? The code stops and then continues? Is any error printed? If you are new at Matlab, is it possible you activated a breakpoint there (red circle)?

Comment: I have gone beyond what I found in the textbook. I have taken a step backward and am just doing the basics to get out basic answers. Stoppage at function definition means exactly that. The code stops there. I am doing one problem per .m file and it is going much better. MM

Comment: My question is whether the code exits (error is thrown, stops working, no way to continue) or the code pauses, so you can hit continue (F5) and the code continues. If it stops there and exits (without any other info), then sorry I can't reproduce your problem, in my machine it runs fine. Also, your specific problem is not clearly represented in your original post.